# Мне нужно вывести не 1 строчку, а все строчки, в которых содержимое столбца ua_mails совпадает с переменной $search_mail

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно вывести не 1 строчку, а все строчки, в которых содержимое столбца ua_mails совпадает с переменной $search_mail.

```html
// класс для работы с БД
class DBi {
    public static $conn;
    public static $lastquery;
 public static function get($args) {
  return self::$conn->$args;
 }
 public static function __callStatic($func, $args) {
  if(is_null(self::$conn)){
   self::$conn = new mysqli("ddd.dddddddddd.dd", "bd_aaa", "ccccccccc", "bd_bbb"); // сервер логин пароль база данных
   if (self::$conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . self::$conn->connect_errno . ') '. self::$conn->connect_error);
   }
   DBi::set_charset("utf8");  
        }
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::$conn, $func), $args);
 }
}
// простой запрос в БД
function mq($sql) {
 $res = DBi::query($sql);
 if (!is_bool($res)) $res->free();
}
// вставить ряд в БД
function mi($sql) {
 $res = DBi::query($sql);
 $id = 0;
 if ($res===true) $id = DBi::get("insert_id");
 if (!is_bool($res)) $res->free();
 return $id;
}
// получаем линию в БД
function mr($sql) {
 $res = DBi::query($sql);
 $row = false;
 if (!is_bool($res) AND $res->num_rows>0)
 $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
 if (!is_bool($res)) $res->free();
 return $row; 
}
// получаем поле из БД
function mf($sql,$field) {
 $res = DBi::query($sql);
 $row = false;
 if (!is_bool($res) AND $res->num_rows>0)
 $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
 if (!is_bool($res)) $res->free();
 if (isset($row[$field])) return $row[$field];
 return false; 
}
// получаем массив в БД
function ma($sql) {
 $res = DBi::query($sql);
 $rows = array();
 if (!is_bool($res) AND $res->num_rows>0) {
  while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) $rows[] = $row;
 }
 if (!is_bool($res)) $res->free();
 return $rows; 
}
// склеивание и препарирование в SET SQL
function sqlset($arr) {
 $out = array();
 foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
  if (is_null($v)) $b = 'NULL'; 
  elseif ($v === "NOW()") $b = 'NOW()'; 
  else $b = "'".DBi::real_escape_string($v)."'";
  $k2 = explode('.',$k); $k1 = array_pop($k2); $k2[] = '`'.$k1.'`';
  $out[] = implode('.',$k2).' = '.$b;
 }
 return implode(', ',$out);
}
// склеивание и препарирование в Mysql Where
function sqlwhere($arr) {
 $out = array();
 foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
  if (is_null($v)) $b = 'NULL'; 
  elseif ($v === "NOW()") $b = 'NOW()'; 
  else $b = "'".DBi::real_escape_string($v)."'";
  $k2 = explode('.',$k); $k1 = array_pop($k2); $k2[] = '`'.$k1.'`';
  $out[] = implode('.',$k2).' = '.$b;
 }
 return implode(' AND ',$out);
}
$w = ma("select `ua_adress` from `user_acc` where ".sqlwhere("ua_mails"=>$search_mail));
foreach ($w as $li) {
  echo $li['ua_adress']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: выглядит не как вопрос, а как задание

Comment: @lexxl, ну как задание было бы без кода, а здесь код есть, на вскидку вроде что-то похожее делает, а что от нас надо - не понятно. То ли код не так работает (тогда как?), то ли еще что. Автор, у вас не нравится `...where ".sqlwhere("ua_mails"=>$search_mail));` - должно быть как минимум `...where ".sqlwhere(array("ua_mails"=>$search_mail)));` Но я код только мельком смотрел, может еще какие косяки есть. Вся информация должна быть в вопросе, а сейчас не понятно в чем именно у вас проблема заключается. Вы может хотите чтобы на косяки кода указали, может еще что, т.к. вопроса, по сути, нет

Comment: автор, возможно, вам сюда [инспекция кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info)

Comment: Пост написан для меня, и я искренне благодарен за предоставленную информацию!

Comment: @Vladimir расскажите, в чём проблема с этим кодом? Если он работает не так, как вы хотите, то опишите подробно фактический и желаемый результаты, а также входные данные.

Comment: @Vladimir подробнее о том, как задать хороший вопрос про SQL: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/

Comment: Если честно код сложный для понимания, посоветовал бы раставить во всех `if`,`while`,`for` и других операторах `{}` скобки, глядишь там и заработает.